# Limit of derivative function at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> $f$ is a differentiable function on real line such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=\alpha$$. Then what can be said about $\alpha$
>
> 1. $\alpha=0$
> 2. $\alpha$ may not be $0$ but $|\alpha| \le1$
> 3. $\alpha\geq1$
> 4. $\alpha\leq-1$

I cannot think of any viable option other than 1,but i cannot prove it. Any hint or solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Surely for a limit to exist at infinity the gradient as it tends to that point must tend to zero

Comment: @HenryLee intuitionally it seems correct but how can i prove it?

Comment: try applying the mean-value theorem

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.  For any a and b, there exist c between a and b  such that $f(b)- f(a)= f'(c)(b- a)$.  Take the limit as b goes to infinity.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773890/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function

Comment: Maybe so? $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{h}=0.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Are you sure you can swap those limits? I had the same solution but was not sure about that step.

Comment: @HenryLee Yes, _if_ the limit of the derivative _exists_ it must be $0$. In fact  the limit need not exist.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You need some argument (which I doubt exists) to justify swapping those limits. (If limits commuted this way just automatically then a lot of theorems would be trivial, and a lot of non-theorems would be true...)

Comment: @David C. Ullrich It's given that the limit exists. See please better the given. I really don't like your tone.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What "tone"? What you  said is wrong, or at least contains a huge gap.  So  I said so. It's a simple fact that many theorems in analysis are of the form $\lim_x\lim_y=\lim_y\lim_x$; mentioning this is the easiest way to  show that you really can't argue this way (without additional justification).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Fine, the limit exists. How  does that show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{h\to0}=\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{x\to\infty}$? (If $f(n,m)=\frac n{n+m}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}$ both exist, but they're not equal.)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Above is an example where you can't swap limits. An example of an (easy) theorem that would be trivialized if swapping limits always worked: If $f_n\to  f$ uniformly and each $f_n$ is continuous then $f$ is continuous. Just _stating_ "$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to a}f_n(x)$" does not prove that. (_Because_ if that argument were correct it could  be used  to  show that a pointwise limit of continuous functions is continuous...)

Answer (score 2):

By the process of elimination:

- Taking $f(x)=1$ eliminates answers $3$ and $4$.
- Let's assume that $\alpha$ could be nonzero, that is, there exists some $f$ that satisfies both conditions, and $\alpha\neq 0$. Let $\lambda>\neq0$. Then, define $$g(x)=\lambda\cdot f(x) - \lambda + 1.$$ It is then easy to see that $g$ satisfies condition $1$, i.e. it has a limit of $1$, and its derivative has a limit of $\lambda$. Therefore, we have just proven that if *some* nonzero $\alpha$ is possible, then *all* real values are possible, so $|\alpha|\leq 1$ is not the correct answer either.

Therefore, $\alpha=0$ must be the correct answer.

---

Now I know, that's not what we really want here. We'd rather actually prove that $\alpha=0$. To do that, consider the following facts:

- If $\alpha > 0$, then there exists some $M$ such that $f'(x)>\frac\alpha2$ for all $x>M$.
- $f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t) dt + f(0)$
- For any integrable $g$, we have $\int_0^x g(t) dt=\int_0^M g(t)dt + \int_M^x g(t) dt$.
- For any pair of integrable functions $f, g$, if $g(x)>h(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ then $\int_a^b g(x)dx > \int_a^b h(x)dx$.

Comment: surely you meant $f'$ under the integrals, not $f$ right?

Comment: Do you think it's also possible for $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ to not exist?

Comment: @Ovi Of course, it's possible. But not the topic of this question.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently large $ x $ , $ f'$ is locally integrable so we can apply FTC . Let $ a> 0$, By FTC $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{x-a}^{x+a} f'(y) dy=\lim_{x \to \infty}(f (x+a)-f (x-a))=0$

If you take $|\alpha| >0$ you get contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Because $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$, $y=1$ is a horizontal asymptote of the graph of $f(x)$.

Therefore, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$.